# Share internet to windows phone 7.5 through wifi

Tags: 12.04, windows, phone

I have a windows 7.5 phone with which I would like to share internet with through wifi. The problem is that windows phone does not support adhoc connections and hence I cannot simply share internet with it. Anyone has any ideas/solutions?

Digvijay

Comment: We need more details. What does the windows phone support?

Comment: Hey. It supports connecting to the wireless access points and AFAIK  it supports vpn.

Comment: @digvijay91 Please keep your question in one thread. Delete duplicates - http://askubuntu.com/questions/138733/how-to-create-a-wireless-access-point-in-precisestep-by-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running your laptop as an access point, this is only possible if your wireless adapter supports going into the `master mode`. If it does not support this, you're totally out of luck.

How to test `master mode` and configure access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode

Helpful threads to setup wireless access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=376283

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663788